# How to filter request using IP restrictions OR a filtering rule

Tags: iis, ip, useragent, traffic-filtering

We have an IIS site right now that has an allow list for a specific list of IP addresses, and all other IPs denied by default. We want to add another rule, that states that if the request coming in as a user-agent of a specific value, then allow it, regardless of if the IP is on the allow list or not. Is this possible?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: IIS 7.5 windows server 2008 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an easy solution for you in the stock IIS functionality. The [`<ipSecurity>`](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity) HTTP module doesn't support factoring-in the `User-Agent`  as part of the block decision, and the [`<filteringRules>`](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules) module doesn't support using the client IP address.

I think you're going to be stuck writing a custom [IIS module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757040.aspx) to do what you want.

Do remember that the User-Agent field is under the control of the client, so basing some kind of security decision on it is probably ill advised.